# language-babel doesn't properly auto complete JSX tags in Atom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, atom-editor

I installed the language-babel package in Atom, and I am currently using React.js. I searched everywhere and it says language-babel should auto complete all my JSX tags in .js files in Atom - tags such as divs, h1, p, etc. However, this still doesn't work... I tried changing language mode to Javascript and to language-babel.

Please help!